# Why isn't conformal mapping more flexible?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I have been spending some time familiarizing myself with the basics of conformal mapping, and found myself somewhat stumped with the limitations of some of the methods I have encountered. Möbius transformations or Schwarz-Christoffel maps, for example, have very strict requirements on where and how they can map the unit disk.

My intuition, however, is that conformal maps should be a lot more general, and a lot more flexible than they are. Consider for example the shape to on the right side in the figure below. Imagine that the three blue closed lines correspond to [topographic contour lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line) of a monotonous hill. Since the hill is monotonous, you can walk to the lowest contour and/or the summit from any point within the hill by walking perpendicular (summit paths: orange lines) up or down the contours (blue closed lines). Since the summit paths and topographic contours are always orthogonal to each other and exist at any point within the hill, the properties of a conformal map (as I understand them) are preserved. So shouldn't there be a conformal mapping from the unit disk (left) to this hill?

Is there something I have misunderstood?

[image]

Comment: See [Riemann mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem).

Comment: Yes there is such a map, and more generally from the disk to any open, bounded, and simply connected set - a fact better known as the Riemann mapping theorem. Schwarz-Christoffel gives special maps because it is *about* special maps, those to polygons.

Comment: @TokenToucan: I see! So is there a way to construct this mapping if I have, for example, a few of the contour paths?

Comment: On the other hand, there is not likely to be a conformal map from the unit disk to the figure on the right that takes the blue and yellow curves on the left to those on the right.

Comment: For example, every conformal map from a disk to a disk is a Möbius transformation, and therefore takes any circle or straight line to a circle or straight line.

Comment: The Möbius transformations of the disk to the disk form a $3$-parameter family (you can specify where $0$ goes to in the interior of the disk, and where $1$ goes to on the circle, and that's all), and so the conformal maps from any simply connected region to another also form a $3$-parameter family.

Comment: @Robert Israel: Thank you for the response. To aid my understanding: why couldn't there be a mapping from the lines in the unit disk to the ones on the right? (Aside from the fact that it's a simple, imperfect sketch I made.) I expect that Möbius transformations might not be complex enough to create a shape like the one I provided, but does this mean that a more complex mapping couldn't exist? (whether we would be able to formulate it is a different matter)

Comment: @J.Galt Here is an MO answer which discusses finding conformal maps to given shapes: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314189/how-to-find-a-conformal-map-of-the-unit-disk-on-a-given-simply-connected-domain/314192

Comment: If $U$ is your region and $f_0: \mathbb D \to U$ is one conformal map, then for any other conformal map $f: \mathbb D \to U$, $f_0^{-1} \circ f$ is a conformal map from $\mathbb D$ to $\mathbb D$, and therefore a Möbius transformation $T$.  Thus $f = f_0 \circ T$, i.e. all conformal maps from $\mathbb D$ to $U$ are obtained by composition of this one conformal map $f_0$ and a Möbius transformation from the disk to itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of three methods for making a conformal mapping that is not as simple as Moebius transforms and (simple) applications of Schwarz-Christoffel.  One reason that the examples you are seeing are "simple" is that the space of shapes (your blue curves) is infinite dimensional and does not have a nice structure (for instance, is not a vector space).  Being infinite dimensional, one is inclined to use an infinite amount of data to specify an arbitrary shape -- every shape gives an infinite set of coefficients.  However, not every infinite set of coefficients describes a shape -- it is easy for such a representation scheme to yield many objects that fail to be connected, which is a problem for this application.

The "nice" thing about Moebius transforms and Schwarz-Christoffel is that using either only requires a small (finite) amount of information.  But this means that these methods cannot give maps that are *too* complicated.  Although, one can increase the complexity via Schwarz-Christoffel by subdividing one's piecewise linear approximations more and more finely.

Luteberget has an [overview](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/52106179.pdf) of the three methods I list below.

(1) Using complicated Schwarz-Christoffel.  See the work of Driscoll and Trefethen, for example, https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ec28/b851707a35630faf58fdb5690f31cc814b15.pdf , references thereto, and their subsequent work, e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.03696 .

(2) Use Stephenson's circle packing method, for example, [http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall09/Stephenson97.pdf](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/%7Emisha/Fall09/Stephenson97.pdf) , and references thereto.

(3) Use Marshall's "ZIPPER" algorithm.  Examples are visible here: [http://sites.math.washington.edu/~marshall/zipper.html](http://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emarshall/zipper.html) .  More recent work on ZIPPER: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605532 .

Comment: Thank you for the response! So if I had, for example, the blue lines not as infinitely-dimensional objects but as minimum curvature (or some other unique) spline interpolation between a finite number of points, the problem would be more well-behaved?

Comment: @J.Galt  Possibly.  It is worth remembering that it takes (potentially) infinitely many parameters to specify the outermost blue curve, which we can be absolutely certain we can produce.  The CR equations constrain what happens inside that boundary and your yellow and blue curves may or may not be simultaneously obtainable (generally, not).  Restriction to a particular class of curves may help or hinder matching and determining which is the case is hard.  At the very least, restriction to a finite set of parameters may make this testable by a finite computation.